# How do I make all application windows open in the middle?

Tags: gnome, window, mutter

I have /org/gnome/mutter/center-new-windows set to true, but many applications do not support this feature and open randomly in different places. I'm wondering how I can make applications like vscodium, keepassxc, joplin open in the center of the screen? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the application does not support the use of the app that forces centering how can it work? Therefore, no I do not think you can magically make it work.

Comment: @David

In x11 you can use --geometry to force positioning of applications, but unfortunately this does not work correctly in wayland. For example, in kde the above applications, except keepassxc, are also not centered in the global setting, but for each individual application you can set up forced geometry and activate it at startup, regardless of whether the application supports it or not. So perhaps there are some other centering options in gnome(wayland).

Comment: +1 Your question seems useful. However, please [format your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) with enough [details](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) so that one can find an adequate answer. Details like Ubuntu and Gnome shell version would be helpful.